# How to use entity's data in home page without authorization in angular 5

Tags: java, angular, angular5, jhipster

hello I want to try to use entity's data in home page without authorization in angular and here is my some code

ChartsComponent

```
isSaving: boolean;
mass = [];
directions: Direction[];


constructor(private jhiAlertService: JhiAlertService,
            private directionService: DirectionService,
) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    // res: HttpResponse<Direction[]>;
     this.isSaving = false;
    this.directionService.query()
        .subscribe((res: HttpResponse<Direction[]>) => {
            this.directions = res.body;
        }, (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message));
}


private onError(error: any) {
    this.jhiAlertService.error(error.message, null, null);
}
```

ChartsComponent.html

```
<div *ngFor="let d of directions">
{{d.id}} {{d.name}}
</div>
```

and in home.component.html I just call `<jhi-charts></jhi-charts>`

but there is an error in console `GET http://localhost:9060/api/directions 401 (Unauthorized)`

thank you in advance

Comment: That would be up to the backend, there's nothing you can do from Angular

Comment: but can I give an access for api/directions

Comment: Yes, but then you would have to provide the backend with proof of that access, i.e. you would need to use authorization

Comment: I agree with @user184994. Because if you dont give proof, means your API would be open and not secure.

Comment: Another option is to render your data to the template and read it from there.

Comment: @AbduqodirUbaydullayev please mark some answer as right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you use `JHipster` (by tags). `JHipster` uses `Spring Boot` under the hood, and to give you anonymous access to some `REST` endpoint, you should in configuration class file like - `java/config/SecurityConfiguration` (it extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class) provide access to it.

Find out the method `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)`, and add `.antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()` to give permission.

For example, my config looks like:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/admin/login").permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority(rolesForAdmin)
      .antMatchers("/subscriber-register/**").permitAll()
    .and()
      .csrf().disable().httpBasic().disable().cors();
}
```